# How to add test project over an existing project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, project

I have a project which is still being developed.

I want to make unit tests in another project but i couldn't manage to use the existing source files.

Say that, i have header1 and source1 in actual project. I want to include hedaer1, source1 and testSource1 files in the test project. And whenever i update the code in header1 or source1 in the actual project, it must be updated automatically in the test project.

I can include the headers in test project, but can not compile. Seems like i have to link static or dinamically in the test project. Is there any solution ? By the way, i'm using Boost test framework, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with GTest framework (but I think it does not matter). So I found 2 possible solutions:

- Change output type of the tested project.

Make tested project output as "static library" ( Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Configuration Type - Static Library (.lib) ), then add the library file to the testing project (Project - Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies - Path to lib file from tested project)
there is article to read http://leefrancis.org/2010/11/17/google-test-gtest-setup-with-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-c/

OR

- Add files from tested project to testing project through menu Project - Add Existing Item (choose *.h and *.cpp files you need).

If someone has more convenient solution to the problem it would be great to know it.